# Can you create a CSV with some of the header columns being blank?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I need to create CSVs from a SQL Server database. The file requirements are specific.

But I can't figure out how to create a flat file where *some* of the header columns are blank. For example, let's say my data is going to have 30 columns. Some number of them, let's say 15, will have a defined header whereas the other 15 should have a blank/empty header.

The header row would look something like this where columns 3 & 5 have no header value:

```
Col1Header,Col2Header,,Col4Header,,Col6Header
```

I've tried doing this in SSMS and VS 2019. SSMS allows me to do " " (space) for the header for multiple columns but VS requires unique column header values. My target system might accept the headers with spaces, and I'll try that, but as of now the team is generating this out of Excel which because it's not in table format allows them to have blank headers when they export to CSV.

Thanks in advance for the support!

Comment: Read  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values or the 4180 https://www.loc.gov/preservation/digital/formats/fdd/fdd000323.shtml

Comment: Please edit with the SQL/method you have tried so may assist you best here.

Comment: Yes, you can create a CSV with blank headers. There is no technical reason a CSV can't have a blank header field name; it's just a text file. Does that answer your question? If you have a question about how to do it with a certain technology, please indicate what you've done so we can get a sense of where you need help.

Comment: What exactly did you try in VS? It seems like if you are using a programming language like C# you can do this pretty easily using file operations. Or even by using PowerShell or some such you could have a post-processing step to parse the CSV file and discard the column headers you didn't want, even if your SQL statement generated a CSV file with all the column headers.